# Problems in Mac Lion Software compiler problems .. correct setup process required

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, osx-lion

The system has been useing Macports.  I configured the system exactly as per the line by line instructions of [these guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX).  In the process I got the error below.  The only change I have from it is that instead of using easy_install I did easy_install-2.6.  I feel it is a CXX error something which is kind of above my knowledge.  Can some one help me in setting up my Mac correctly?  I am a heavy user of Xcode (iPhone development) and a Roboticist and need a compiler for executing C files.  I would also be willing on working with Python for this and future setups (wsgi applications).  I have a 64-bit OSX Lion running currently.

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
  -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
  -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
  -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
  -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
  -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  [rosbuild] Building package rosconsole
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build
  cd build && make -l8
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target rosconsole
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.o
  /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.cpp:684: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <URL:http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter> for instructions.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/src/rosconsole/rosconsole.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosconsole.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rosconsole written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/rajeshmedampudi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111107-233014/rosconsole/build_output.log                      
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rosconsole [FAIL] [ 7.71 seconds ]                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rosconsole. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit [PASS] [ 24.44 seconds ]                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosgraph [PASS] [ 24.44 seconds ]                                                                                                                                         
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 24.44 seconds ]                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Built 28 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] /Users/rajeshmedampudi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111107-233014                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.22', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 679, in <module>

  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 670, in rosinstall_main

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 488, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is the Config problem i am having while i am trying to compile with my current llvm-gcc 
This is the config.log(in full) as you already must be knowing i am a little inexperienced with the compiler changes and all...

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by llvm configure 3.1svn, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.60.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt --enable-optimized

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Rajeshs-Mac-Pro.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 11.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 141 tasks, 759 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 0.99, Mach factor: 7.00
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2067: checking for C compiler version
configure:2074: clang --version >&5
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:2077: $? = 0
configure:2084: clang -v >&5
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.10.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
Thread model: posix
configure:2087: $? = 0
configure:2094: clang -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:2097: $? = 1
configure:2120: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2147: clang -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2150: $? = 0
configure:2196: result: a.out
configure:2201: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2211: ./a.out
configure:2214: $? = 0
configure:2231: result: yes
configure:2238: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2240: result: no
configure:2243: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2250: clang -o conftest -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2253: $? = 0
configure:2277: result: 
configure:2283: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2309: clang -c -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments conftest.c >&5
configure:2312: $? = 0
configure:2335: result: o
configure:2339: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2368: clang -c -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments conftest.c >&5
configure:2374: $? = 0
configure:2381: test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2384: $? = 0
configure:2391: test -s conftest.o
configure:2394: $? = 0
configure:2408: result: yes
configure:2413: checking whether clang accepts -g
configure:2443: clang -c -g -Qunused-arguments conftest.c >&5
configure:2449: $? = 0
configure:2456: test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2459: $? = 0
configure:2466: test -s conftest.o
configure:2469: $? = 0
configure:2599: result: yes
configure:2616: checking for clang option to accept ISO C89
configure:2690: clang  -c -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments conftest.c >&5
configure:2696: $? = 0
configure:2703: test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2706: $? = 0
configure:2713: test -s conftest.o
configure:2716: $? = 0
configure:2736: result: none needed
configure:2870: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:2877: llvm-g++ --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2880: $? = 0
configure:2887: llvm-g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
configure:2890: $? = 0
configure:2897: llvm-g++ -V >&5
llvm-g++-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:2900: $? = 1
configure:2903: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:2932: llvm-g++ -c  -Qunused-arguments conftest.cpp >&5
configure:2938: $? = 0
configure:2945: test -z "$ac_cxx_werror_flag" || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2948: $? = 0
configure:2955: test -s conftest.o
configure:2958: $? = 0
configure:2972: result: yes
configure:2977: checking whether llvm-g++ accepts -g
configure:3007: llvm-g++ -c -g -Qunused-arguments conftest.cpp >&5
configure:3013: $? = 0
configure:3020: test -z "$ac_cxx_werror_flag" || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:3023: $? = 0
configure:3030: test -s conftest.o
configure:3033: $? = 0
configure:3163: result: yes
configure:3191: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3321: result: llvm-gcc-4.2
configure:3350: llvm-gcc-4.2 -Qunused-arguments conftest.c
conftest.c:13: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'error'
configure:3356: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "llvm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "-llvm-"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1svn"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "llvm 3.1svn"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:3350: llvm-gcc-4.2 -Qunused-arguments conftest.c
conftest.c:13: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'error'
configure:3356: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "llvm"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "-llvm-"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1svn"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "llvm 3.1svn"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:3432: error: C preprocessor "llvm-gcc-4.2" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-Qunused-arguments
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-Qunused-arguments
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=llvm-gcc-4.2
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=llvm-g++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_prog_CPP=llvm-gcc-4.2
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cxx_g=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALL_BINDINGS=''
AR=''
ARCH=''
BINDINGS_TO_BUILD=''
BINPWD=''
BINUTILS_INCDIR=''
BUILD_CC=''
BUILD_CXX=''
BUILD_EXEEXT=''
BZIP2=''
CAT=''
CC='clang'
CFLAGS='-Qunused-arguments'
CIRCO=''
CLANG_SRC_ROOT=''
CMP=''
CONVENIENCE_LTDL_FALSE=''
CONVENIENCE_LTDL_TRUE=''
CP=''
CPP='llvm-gcc-4.2'
CPPFLAGS='-Qunused-arguments'
CVSBUILD=''
CXX='llvm-g++'
CXXFLAGS='-g -O2'
DATE=''
DEBUG_RUNTIME=''
DEBUG_SYMBOLS=''
DEFS=''
DISABLE_ASSERTIONS=''
DOT=''
DOTTY=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_CBE_PRINTF_A=''
ENABLE_DOCS=''
ENABLE_DOXYGEN=''
ENABLE_EMBED_STDCXX=''
ENABLE_EXPENSIVE_CHECKS=''
ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=''
ENABLE_PIC=''
ENABLE_POLLY=''
ENABLE_PROFILING=''
ENABLE_PTHREADS=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
ENABLE_THREADS=''
ENABLE_TIMESTAMPS=''
ENABLE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN=''
ENDIAN=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPENSIVE_CHECKS=''
EXTRA_LD_OPTIONS=''
EXTRA_OPTIONS=''
FDP=''
FIND=''
GAS=''
GRAPHVIZ=''
GREP=''
GROFF=''
GV=''
GZIPBIN=''
HAVE_LINK_VERSION_SCRIPT=''
HAVE_PERL=''
HAVE_PTHREAD=''
HOST_OS=''
HUGE_VAL_SANITY=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_LTDL_FALSE=''
INSTALL_LTDL_TRUE=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
JIT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBADD_DL=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LINKALL=''
LLVM_BINDIR=''
LLVM_CONFIGTIME=''
LLVM_COPYRIGHT='Copyright (c) 2003-2011 University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.'
LLVM_CROSS_COMPILING=''
LLVM_DATADIR=''
LLVM_DOCSDIR=''
LLVM_ENUM_ASM_PARSERS=''
LLVM_ENUM_ASM_PRINTERS=''
LLVM_ENUM_DISASSEMBLERS=''
LLVM_ENUM_TARGETS=''
LLVM_ETCDIR=''
LLVM_HAS_POLLY=''
LLVM_INCLUDEDIR=''
LLVM_INFODIR=''
LLVM_LIBDIR=''
LLVM_MANDIR=''
LLVM_ON_UNIX=''
LLVM_ON_WIN32=''
LLVM_PREFIX=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MKDIR=''
MMAP_FILE=''
MV=''
NEATO=''
NM=''
NOLINKALL=''
NO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS=''
NO_VARIADIC_MACROS=''
OBJEXT='o'
OCAMLC=''
OCAMLDEP=''
OCAMLDOC=''
OCAMLOPT=''
OCAML_LIBDIR=''
OPTIMIZE_OPTION=''
OS=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu'
PACKAGE_NAME='llvm'
PACKAGE_STRING='llvm 3.1svn'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='-llvm-'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.1svn'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PDFROFF=''
PERL=''
POD2HTML=''
POD2MAN=''
RANLIB=''
RDYNAMIC=''
RM=''
RPATH=''
RUNTEST=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIBEXT=''
SHLIBPATH_VAR=''
TAR=''
TARGETS_TO_BUILD=''
TARGET_HAS_JIT=''
TARGET_OS=''
TCLSH=''
TWOPI=''
USE_OPROFILE=''
USE_UDIS86=''
XDOT_PY=''
ZIP=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
ifGNUmake=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/opt'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target=''
target_alias=''
target_cpu=''
target_os=''
target_vendor=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "llvm"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "-llvm-"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.1svn"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "llvm 3.1svn"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu"

configure: exit 1
```

Now i did not find any material of how to go about in installing llvm-chang in my system where do you need to install it and how to go about it. do you know of any such... It would be a great help in clearing this out... thanks.

PS: this is the guide i am [using](http://shapeof.com/archives/2010/01/using_the_latest_llvm_with_xcode.html). i tried making downloading the files to /usr/llvm and they did download but got stuck at the .configure part.... do you want me to specify any other form of messages that need to be done in setting up the mac compiler correctly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems that the Python that comes installed with the Lion software seems to have been messe with. What i Basically did was to create a new login and then carry on the installation process with easy-install2.6 . rather than use easy install easy_install

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines you are referring to are outdated, please check the users guide on their website

Comment: hey steve.... my system has the problem.. i am not able to do any compile options... so how could it be a problem with thier... procedure.

Comment: what compiler version are you using?

Comment: I think I  am using the basic compiler that comes with lion I don't think I changed any thing. Now I am trying to make the default compiler as llvm cheng.

Comment: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files is the response when i just place gcc gcc-V doesnot work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the package `apple-gcc42` and force the compiler to GCC instead of LLVM? Xcode 4.2 uses LLVM by default and it does not come with GCC anymore.

Comment: hmm.. but what are its advantages of moving to the apple-gcc42... will it be compatible if i send the project files of xcode from my computer to someone to test them on theirs... what is the difference between llvm-cheng, llvm-ggc and apple-gcc42.... did you actually update the new xcode 4.2.1 it has a fix with "-Apple LLVM compiler support c++11 features and the LLVM libc++ standard ibrary" would installing that solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just ran into the same problem on Mac OS X Lion (10.7).
So far, this workaround worked for me:

change to the directory ..../ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build
and call 'make'. This should produce the same error again.
Now call 'make -n' which prints out the commands which are really called by make.
Pick the (long) line where it compiles (c++) rosconsole.cpp from them, change the optimization option from -O2 to -O0 (thats MINUS OHH ZERO) and execute that command. 
Then call make again to let it finish its work.